# Output behaviour of relational operators when used in printf - C Language

Tags: c

This is the code that i was trying :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int k = 35;
    int x = (k==35);
    printf("%d %d %d %d", (k==35), k=50, (k>40), x); // gives output => 0 50 0 1
    printf("\n%s",k==35); // gives output => (null)
    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering that a relational check returns Boolean `true` or `false`. Even when converted to integer type it should become `0` for `false` and `1` for `true`. What am i missing?

Comment: You're not missing anything. Why do you think you are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your `k=50` with a single `=` is an *assignment operator*; since it appears in a list of arguments, the order of evaluation of arguments is undefined, and you get stuck by [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The compiler is free to pass `(k>40)` before or after doing `k=50`

BTW, with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) version 4.9 on Debian/Sid, when compiling your code with

```
gcc -Wall danglingcruze.c -o danglingcruze
```

I am warned by the compiler:

```
danglingcruze.c:2:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
 main(){
 ^
danglingcruze.c: In function ‘main’:
danglingcruze.c:5:37: warning: operation on ‘k’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     printf("%d %d %d %d", (k==35), k=50, (k>40), x); // gives output => 0 50 0 1
                                     ^
danglingcruze.c:5:37: warning: operation on ‘k’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
danglingcruze.c:6:5: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, 
        but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     printf("\n%s",k==35); // gives output => (null)
     ^
```

Comment: Yes that outputs 50 and that is okay for me. The problem is when i compare even if it is true it returns 0.

Comment: Okay, I think i got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Order of evaluation of parameters in a function is not guaranteed. You are modifying `k` in one of the parameter and using its value in other parameters. That's why it invokes undefined behavior. An example of similar case

```
int i = 1;
printf("%d %d\n", i++, ++i); // Undefined behavior.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int k = 35;
    int x = (k==35); // x =1
    printf("%d %d %d %d", (k==35), k=50, (k>40), x); // gives output => 0 50 0 1
    // k=50 changed your value
    printf("\n%s",k==35); // gives output => (null)
    // => printf %s + 0 => null 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know but for me `printf("\n%d",k==35);` it is giving 0 as output.

Comment: Yes, why 0? why not 1?

Comment: Isn't it an undefined behavior then? I am not able to understand what it is you're trying to convey?

Comment: k==35 it will return 1 but `printf` takes address of an variable as an argument.
And 1 is not a valid address.

Comment: @DanglingCruze `k == 35` returns 0 because you did `k = 50`.

Comment: @sutirtha The %d format expects an integer as an argument, not an address.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that i'm assigning the value inside function parameter which is causing the undefined behavior. Thank you :)